# Node globby error while using multi patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I use node glob which is working OK .
I use it for one folder1 like following

```
      glob('folder1/*.js'), function(err, files){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not able to get files from folder: ', err);
        } else {
            files.forEach(function (file) {
```

https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Now I want to read in one shot from folder2 also and I try to use globby like following and I got error

```
    globby(['folder1/*.js','folder2/*.js']).then( function(err, files){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not able to get files from folder: ', err);
        } else {
            //Get plugin configuration & provided actions
            files.forEach(function (file) {
```

https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby

in this case the files are coming as **undfiend** and I got to the error  any idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `err` argument from the `then` callback. Use `catch` to handle errors
`globby(['folder1/*.js','folder2/*.js']).then( function(files){...}).catch(function(err){...})`